# Can’t access website since upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-88-generic x86_64), when I try to access my websites, I am getting

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I have made sure all apt are up to date.

`mysqli.so` is installed and I have located it in: `/usr/lib/php/20190902`

Several pieces of advice suggest making sure the path in the `php.ini` file point to where the `mysqli.so` is located.

Running `php–ini` shows:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
```

When I try to edit `php.ini` using `sudo nano php.ini` the file is empty other than the PHP commented out help information.

Am I doing this right?
How can I edit the `php.ini` to check the path to the `mysqli.so` file?

Comment: That's what it says when it boots up

Comment: try different browser

Comment: I'm getting the same "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress" in diferent browsers

Answer (score 0):

Usually with apache the php.ini path is /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini with nginx it's /etc/php/7.4/fpm/  etc... CLI is use only for php runs in terminal.

Use

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

to check.

Seem some recommended php extension for hosting wordpress are missing. => https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/server-environment/

curl, mbstring and zip

```
sudo apt install php-curl php-mbstring php-zip
```

Also what are the return of

```
systemctl status apache2
systemctl status nginx
```

Comment: This is the result: 

php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

Comment: Using sudo nano php.ini the file is empty other than the PHP commented out help information.

Comment: php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
apcu
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
json
libxml
memcache
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: LAMP:
Linux :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
MySql Version:
mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
PHP Version:
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Zend Engine v3.4.0, 
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3
I’m having difficulty finding Apache2 details.